# How do I update a json object value by referencing itself in a sqlite table?

Tags: json, sqlite

Let's say I have a table `features` which has a column `data` that contains json objects.

```
CREATE TABLE features ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data json )
```

Now, an example data object may be:

```
{"A":
   {"B":
      {"coordinates":[
         {"x":1, "y":1},
         {"x":10, "y":10}
       ]
    }
}
```

Now I need to go through all the data in this `data` column and double the value of the `coordinates`.

I tried setting it to its own value divided by 0.5 but this seems to work for the first row and then sets all other rows to that exact same value.

```
update features
set data = 
(select json_set(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x", (select json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x")/0.5 from features))
from features);
```

How do I reference its own value in `json_set` and keep repeating for each row? What is the best way to go through each row and double the coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a `SELECT` statement.
You can refer directly to the value of the column `data` in the same row:

```
UPDATE features
SET data = json_set(
             features.data, 
             "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x", json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x") * 2
           );
```

Or, if you want to update all `x`s and `y`s:

```
UPDATE features
SET data = json_set(
             features.data, 
             "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x", json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[0].x") * 2,
             "$.A.B.coordinates[0].y", json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[0].y") * 2,
             "$.A.B.coordinates[1].x", json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[1].x") * 2,
             "$.A.B.coordinates[1].y", json_extract(features.data, "$.A.B.coordinates[1].y") * 2
       );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=81bf6ad8959c50435da1a0ff8e26917f).